would a basic question about m&a terminology be better suited here or money.stackexchange.com?
I had a basic question about an M&A term, and first attempted to post here. However no tags existed for "merger" or "acquisition" or "enterprise-value." I then noticed that most of the questions here are extremely advanced and math oriented.
So, I posted on money.stackexchange.com instead. Here is my question: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/78110/why-is-minority-interest-included-in-enterprise-value
That site has the opposite risk (too basic and consumer oriented) but it did have a tag for corporate-acquisitions, and I had a relatively detailed question about option counter-parties answered successfully there earlier.
I see that this site is still new, so my question is perhaps aspirational: Would you WANT questions like the above to be posted here? Or are they too basic and not sufficiently math-y?

I've brought up the suggestion of a Business Finance and Accounting SE that could potentially cover this type of question.
It would seem that with the demise of Startups, there is a huge need for this type of community.

To my best knowledge, there is no StackExchange website that deal with topics like that. Maybe you can try in Economics, but the website is going to be shut down :(

Interesting. Not enough activity?

Unfortunately, yes :(
